# Journey Builder recurring based on Date field

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, date, scheduled

I have a question about Journey Builder. 
I have built a journey that is supposed to evaluate contacts on a monthly basis based on specific date field.

I have configured the schedule as recurring with the following set up.

[image: Schedule set up]

My question is the following: **how should I configure my date field for my journey to be based on that specific date field when evaluating new contacts?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot configure the evaluate new to be based upon the date field in the Data Extension. Seems like you have two choices. 
You will need to Evaluate All and use the [Data Extension entry filters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_create_a_filter.htm&type=5) to reference the date in the Data Extension. If that does not work, you could alternatively use the Event entry to create a [Date Based Entry](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_create_date_based_event.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hi @Amanda Turner, thank you for your reply. Both of the solutions would have work. Nevertheless, I had to find a third solution (client's need has change since yesterday) using a decision split in which I had to specify the date field for each path and then I had to add a wait by attribute based on that sepcific date field in each path. The journey would be configured as "Run Once" at the activation.